# Browser goes to wrong site

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, internet, chrome-for-android, stock-browser

Since yesterday, I cannot browse to www.aemet.es (the Spanish national weather service). Instead, it goes to m.antena3.com (a TV station). This happens both with the built-in browser and with Chrome.

Following the advice found [here](http://www.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=3164928), I've cleared the cache (or I've tried to) but the problem persists. I've also tried a hard reboot.

What else can I do?

My device is a Samsung Galaxy S3, unrooted, running Android 4.1.2

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the ISP's DNS. Have you used WiFi of a different ISP and 3G and get the same results?

Comment: Well, my PC is in the same network and reaches the site just fine. But if I try through 3G, it goes to the wrong one, but a "Forbidden" message appears, instead of opening the site.

Comment: Then problem most probably lies with your ISP, their DNS might be outdated or poisoned to point your browser to a wrong site. You might want to let them know of this issue so they can fix it for you.

Comment: Solved! I've changed the DNS of my router to google's public DNS and now works fine.

Comment: good for you :D this is a common issue also with our ISP that's why I use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) as a counter.